# WPF datagrid binding

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have the following domain:

```
public class FileInformation
{
 public String FileName;
 public String CreatedBy;  // name of user who created the file
 public String CreatedComments;
 public String CreatedDate;
 public String EditedBy;   // name of user who last edited the file
 public String EditedComments;
 public String EditedDate;
}

public class Folder
{
public List<FileInformation> Files {get;set}
}
```

I want to have a WPF datagrid and bind the list of Files in the "Folder" class to it .....It's pretty easy to if I want to have the data displayed in a standard way..... but I want to have it displaYed in the following way:

[image]

Any ideas on what I have to do to have the data displayed in this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is :

- Extract a CollectionView from the Binding:

`CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)(CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_grid.ItemsSource);`

- Create a grouping based on FileName :

`cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("FileName"));`

- Create a GroupStyle in the Grid that displays the Gorup in the way you want it.

```
   <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                      <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header={Binding Name}>
                          <ItemsPresenter/>
                      </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
   </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

The presented style will not didsplay the info exactly as presented in the screenshot but based on this tou could customize the content to match your needs...